# What happens at the end of Impossible Mission II?

Tags: impossible-mission-ii

I was able to finish the first opus when I was young, but I have never been able to finish [Impossible Mission II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_Mission_II).

Has anyone actually finished that game? Could they tell me what actually happens at the end of this game?

Comment: If anyone can explain what's going on in the ending of this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNDeyMLQ68k I think we would have an answer. Normally I would, only I can't for the life of me figure out why a guy dressed in white committed suicide by doing a flip jump off a building and screaming ARRRRRRRRRGGGGH in narmy Commodore 64 sound effects. Or why The End has a question mark.

Comment: No, it's just the "Normal" end for that game, when you run out of time, it's a fancy GAME OVER. (If my memory are good, I think I saw this many time when I was playing that game)

Comment: http://www.textfiles.com/adventure/impossiblemission2.sol Not according to this. He solved the final puzzle, so that definitely seems to be the ending.

Comment: Similarly: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kWtXMaMgW0 and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiO4NHzq3-s&feature=related

Comment: OK, I may have see this somewhere else. I think the "Game over" end was an explosion or something like that.  There is only one remaining concern :
From the .sol link "Now choose one...  but the correct one.". What happen if you don't choose the correct one? I was expecting something like the "NO, NO, NO!" form impossible mission 1 for a correct choice....

Comment: ok, I found from this http://www.neoseeker.com/resourcelink.html?rlid=71816&rid=66470 "Access the wrong 2 and you get fried.". so that the correct end!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best as I can interpret this [ending](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNDeyMLQ68k):

The player character reaches the central tower of Elvin Atombender's fortress and disables all operations by accessing the main terminal. Atombender, the man in white, is driven mad by grief at his inability to take revenge for the player's actions in Impossible Mission 1, and decides that the time has come to escape this mortal coil by doing a front flip off the highest point of his fortress.

> AAAaaaAAAAAAaaAAAAAAaaaaagggghhh

However, the game hints at the possibility that the main character's struggles against Elvin [may not yet be over...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_Mission_2025)

> THE END?

Comment: Oh, boy! What a cliff hanger!